# How do I display an image in browser using a web server in C using fread?

Tags: c, image, http, webserver, fread

I am able to display html and plain text file in the browser using my web server.c. However, when I try to load an image jpeg file, it give me this error "The image http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.jpeg" cannot be displayed because it contains error.

The content-type i have set it as "image/jpeg".

This is my code:

```
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    unsigned char *buffer;

    fp = fopen(page+1,"rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen);
    fread(buffer,fileLen,sizeof(unsigned char),fp);

    fclose(fp);

    write (connection_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

This is the header for my image that i have set

"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
              "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n"
              "Connection: close\r\n"
              "\r\n";

Please kindly advise. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `write()` statement is wrong. The value returned by `strlen(buffer)` will be the location of the first zero byte in the JPEG file. Try using `fileLen` instead.

Here are a few other things that crossed my mind:

1. In the `fread()` call, the second and third arguments should really be the other way round. And since `sizeof(unsigned char)` is `1` by definition, I would have used `fread(buffer,1,fileLen,fp);` instead.
2. You should really check the values returned by `fopen()`, etc.
3. Your use of `page+1` suggests that you're placing an unchecked HTTP query string parameter directly into a file system call. Obviously you don't want to be doing that :-)